# Is it possible to merge multiple django querysets from multiple databases into one queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to create an api with django-rest to get events. For instance: I have a table events in multiple databases. A get request to /events should read all the events from all configured databases and aggregate all results into one queryset. Then I want to serialize the queryset and return the json to the user.

in settings.py I created a list of databases who have the events table.
I can query events from DATABASE_1 and DATABASE_2, with a single query. But when I try to aggregate the results in a loop, then I only get the events from DATABASE_2. So the aggregation isn't working.

How do I aggregate these querysets into one? Or is there even a better solution for querying multiple databases?

settings.py

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db(),
    'DATABASE_1': env.db('DATABASE_1'),
    'DATABASE_2': env.db('DATABASE_2'),
}

EVENT_DATABASES = [
    'DATABASE_1',
    'DATABASE_2',
]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('events/', EventView.as_view())
]
```

event_view.py

```py
class EventView(APIView):
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        last_24_hours = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
        events = Event.objects.none()
        for database in settings.EVENT_DATABASES:
            events |= Event.objects.using(database).filter(updated_at__gte=last_24_hours).exclude(code='OK')
        return events

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = EventSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: You can chain querysets by doing: chain(queryset1, queryset2, ... , querysetN)

Comment: @ChristianBouvier Yes I can chain them that way. 
The problem is that the serializer wants a queryset object, but after chaining I have a chain object. I get the error `'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'model'`. So is there a way to convert that back to a single queryset?
Otherwise chaining isn't the right solution....

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to merge querysets of the same model you can use the `|` operator.

i.e.
`merged_queryset = queryset_1 | queryset_2`

Otherwise, you best friend is [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (as stated in the previous answer). The result of a chain is a chain object you can turn into a list by doing:

`merged_queryset = list(chain(queryset_1, queryset_2))`

Hope this help!